# Convert a string of multi digit numbers into an array of characters

Tags: java, arrays, string, char

I have a string that is a math expression. Example: "((14 + 53) + 62)" and I want to convert the String into an array of chars. Example ['(', '(', '14', '+', '53', '+', '62', ')']

When I use the method .toCharArray on the string, it converts it to an array of characters, but for numbers that are greater than 9 (Multi-Digit), it will split that number into individual digits. Example: ['(', '(', '1', '4', '5', '3', '+' '6', '2', ')']

How would I convert a string that contains multiple digits to an array of characters?

```
public class Testing {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String stringNumbers = "24 23 84 12 41 52 54";

        char[] charNumArray = stringNumbers.toCharArray();
        System.out.println(Arrays.toString(charNumArray));
    }
}
```

Comment: Do you mean an array of Strings?  A character is, well, just one character.

Comment: `'14'` is not a valid char. If your numbers are always going to be separated by space you could do: `String[] numArr = stringNumers.split("\\s+");`

Comment: ahah wow I've been wasting my time. Thank you

Comment: @ GBlodgett But that regex will give the first split component to be "((14" which is probably not what the OP wants.

Comment: The concept you're looking for is *tokenizing*.

Comment: Yeah originally I was thinking if the character ‘14’ could be represented as ascii than it could be represented as the character ‘14’ but I figured out my issue. Thank you all.

Answer (score 0):

Lets say that you need to deal with two operators (+,-);

```
//Case one (+)
String stringNumbers = "24 23 84 12 41 52 54";
```

1.spit it by space.
2.for loop to the Array sum it.
3.print it.

```
//Case two (+,-)
String stringNumbers = "-24+23+84+12-41-52-54";
```

1.Create second null String.
2.replaceAll stringNumbers by ("\+ , ",")
3.loop trough the original string to locate the minus operators,
if (charAt(i)=='-') add to the second String ",-".
4.2.split stringNumbers by ",".
5.repeat steps 2,3 from case one.

```
String s = "-12-5+15-20";
        String t = "";
        s = s.replaceAll("\\+",",");
        for (int i = 0; i < s.length(); i++) {
            if(s.charAt(i)=='-' && i!=0){
                t+=",-";
                continue;
            }
            t+=s.charAt(i);
        }
        String[] st = t.split(",");
        int sum = 0;
        for (int i = 0; i < st.length ; i++) {
            sum+=Integer.valueOf(st[i]);
        }
        System.out.println(sum);
```